# c# tooltip balloon popping up in wrong location

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, tooltip

So I believe this is a common issue seeing as there are numerous posts i have found related to it however none of the workarounds I have found seem to be working.

I am making a windows form application and just want to pop up a warning when a textbox has invalid data. However, the tooltip pops up way below the control it's attached too.

I tried a solution someone else posted by doing a divide on the height and width of the textbox but it didn't change the location at all.

Any ideas?

Looking at the picture, the tooltip should be on the textbox on the top, not the bottom.

```
        private void validateData()
    {
        //check vendor num
        int parsedValue;
        int x = textBoxVendorNum.Width / 2;
        int y = textBoxVendorNum.Height / 10;
            if (!int.TryParse(textBoxVendorNum.Text, out parsedValue))
        {
            toolTip1.ToolTipIcon = ToolTipIcon.Error;
            toolTip1.ToolTipTitle = "Unacceptable Value";
            toolTip1.IsBalloon = true;

            toolTip1.Show("Must be a number",textBoxVendorNum,x,y,5000);
        }

    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `SetToolTip`:

```
private void validateData()
{
    int parsedValue;
    if (!int.TryParse(textBoxVendorNum.Text, out parsedValue))
    {
                tooltip.SetToolTip(textBoxVendorNum, "Unacceptable Value");
                tooltip.ToolTipIcon = ToolTipIcon.Error;
                tooltip.ToolTipTitle = "Unacceptable Value";
                tooltip.IsBalloon = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. This actually worked. I had to put in show("Unacceptable Value", textboxvendornum) again but it showed in the right spot!! Thank you!!